# matplotlib.path.contains_points inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been using `matplotlib.path.contains_points()` method without any figures or plots. I am getting inconsistent results depending on the path. In the following example, a simple square path works, but a longer path from an ellipse does not:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.draw import ellipse_perimeter
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = 100
squarepath = Path([(0,0), (0, s), (s,s), (s, 0)])
print(squarepath.contains_points([(s/2, s/2)]))

(xv,yv) = ellipse_perimeter(200,360,260,360)
xyverts =  np.stack((xv,yv),axis=1)
ellipsepath = Path(xyverts)
pt = (213,300)
print(ellipsepath.contains_points([pt]))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.scatter(ellipsepath.vertices[:,0],ellipsepath.vertices[:,1])
plt.scatter(pt[0],pt[1])
plt.show()
```

I am using `contains_points()` before anything is plotted, so there should not be any data versus display coordinates issue as is discussed in other similar questions about `contains_points()`. What else could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ellipse_perimeter` is returning the points of the ellipse perimeter in an order that does not define a path. Vertices are then created between points accross your ellipse. You can check that by ploting your path as patch instead of using `scatter`:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
ax.add_patch(PathPatch(ellipsepath, facecolor='yellow', lw=1)) # instead of scatter(ellipsepath...)
```

Output (without changing anything else to your code):

[image: ellipse_path_wrong]

As you can see instead of seeing a yellow ellipse as specified with `facecolor`, we only see the lines (linking points all over the perimeter).

I guess the easiest way to solve this would be to use [`patches.Ellipse`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html) and call `get_path()`.

However, if you're stuck with skimage, you'll have to sort your points before creating a path:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.draw import ellipse_perimeter
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

(xv,yv) = ellipse_perimeter(200,360,260,360)
xyverts =  list(zip(xv, yv))
pt_top = sorted([(x,y) for x,y in xyverts if y >= 360], key=lambda c: c[0])
pt_bottom = sorted([(x,y) for x,y in xyverts if y < 360], key=lambda c: -c[0])

xyverts = pt_top + pt_bottom

ellipsepath = Path(xyverts)
pt = (213,300)
print(ellipsepath.contains_points([pt]))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_patch(PathPatch(ellipsepath, facecolor='yellow', lw=1))
plt.scatter(pt[0],pt[1])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]